Do self-powers $n^n$ always form a cycle modulo an integer?
By looking at the first few values, it seems that the self-power $n^n$ always form a cycle modulo an integer.
\begin{align}
n &=> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,... \\
n^n \mod{2} &=> \color{red}{1, 0,} 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 \\
n^n \mod{3} &=> \color{red}{1,1,0,1,2,0,}1,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,1,2\\
n^n \mod{4} &=> \color{red}{1, 0, 3, 0,} 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1 \\
n^n \mod{5} &=> \color{red}{1, 4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 0,} 1, 4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4 \\
n^n \mod{6} &=> \color{red}{1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0,} 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5 \\
\vdots
\end{align}
How would you go to prove or disprove that this is always true?

https://oeis.org/A174824

Nice link. How were you so fast at finding it ?

@Zakhurf At the front oeis.org page, searching for "2,6,4,20,6" (or "1,2,6,4,20,6") gets A174824 as the top result.

A starting point is that $a^b \mod{k}$ is entirely determined by $a \mod{k}$ and $b \mod{φ(k)}$ by Euler's theorem.

If you try mod $8$, you’ll see the cycle doesn’t start right away

@J.W.Tanner It is true that the cycle does not start right away for some higher values, but it seems that the sequence nethertheless converges towards a cycle.

@Zakhurf oeis is a standard (and indispensable) reference for facts like this so I looked there first. Usually there's a proof or a paper reference there in the notes.  Proof given here I believe: https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4066

Duplicate but finding a good target may take a bit of time ...
